How to incrementally train a Face Recognition Model without retraining from scratch?
I'm building a face recognition model. I've already trained a model using the images of two people (Cristiano Ronaldo and Lionel Messi). Now, I want to add more people (e.g., Maria Sharapova) to the model without retraining everything from scratch.
Is there a way to train a model a new model using the new dataset? If so, how can I efficiently merge the new training data with the existing model?
Here is my existing code
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
import os

import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'test': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}

data_dir = './new_dataset'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x), data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'test']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4, shuffle=True)
               for x in ['train', 'test']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True, progress=True)

num_classes = len(class_names)
model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, num_classes)

device = torch.device("cpu")
model = model.to(device)

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for inputs, labels in dataloaders['train']:
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.pth')

model.eval()

correct = 0
total = 0

with torch.no_grad():
    for inputs, labels in dataloaders['test']:
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)

        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

accuracy = 100 * correct / total
print(f"Accuracy on the test set: {accuracy}%")

The folder, ./new_dataset looks like this
new_dataset/
--test/
----cristiano_ronaldo
----lione_messi
--train/
----cristiano_ronaldo
----lione_messi


Usually people use fine-tuning approach - to train only a few layers of the network (typically the final few layers, or fc in your case). For this you can set model.eval() and model.fc.train(), then train on the new dataset with 3 people. It should be much faster than turning the whole model. Note that you should train on all 3 people, because otherwise the network will quickly forget the knowledge about previous faces.

Look into metric learning, arc-face and triplet loss. Standard classification is hard for facial recognition because you have to retrain the model (at least the final layer) every time you want to add a new person/class. The preferred method is to map faces to embeddings and measure cosine similarity between a given query face and a set of reference face embeddings. Also if you're not doing it already, you should have a face detection model that bounds/crops just the face of input images. The facial recognition model should only process cropped faces
